# Generic SqliteopenHelper Class for all activity

Tags: android, oop, android-sqlite

I have a two database file in my project.

1. Available in assets folder(open using SqliteOpenHelper class)
2. Created on runtime(create and open using SqliteOpenHelper class)

Which is the best practice?

- Keep two databases separately and open those using two different classes(which extends SqliteOpenHelper class)
- Keep assets database and create extra tables in existing database and use same Helper class

I am trying to use same Helper class for both assests database and runtime creation database.

Also my Application has Activities with multiple fragments and Multiple cursor Loaders. I need to use generic helper class for sqlite.

Comment: i don't think ```SqliteOpenHelper``` can deal with the assets database. it needs the database file to be in the databases folder

Comment: Yes.Database file should copied to database folder from assets folder.Then use SQLiteOpenHelper normally.My question is,if i have some other tables,can i add these table to existing Database file or I create a new Database file using SQLiteOpenHelper and create these tables on new Datadabase. I know we can do this. But in this method two classes are extends SQLiteOpenHelper. To reduce coding I try to make those two classes same.

Comment: You have to explain what is the responsibilities of each database. Why do you need two in the first place?  .. the answer depends totally on these.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to copy the sqlite db file from assets to file directory (/data/data/files/) in `onCreate` of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` and then if you need to create extra tables at runtime, you can use the same db. This way you reduce the overhead of using 2 sqlite files and 2 helper class.

Answer (score 0):

Always try to make your desing based on **loose coupling**,

So you should make an class to work for sql operations , if you need different parameters or different tables , you should encapsulate them. May be you can create a tableFactory ? But you should design your code more cohesive and loosely coupled...